# Migrate only Stored procedure from SQL Server to mysql automatically

Tags: mysql, sql-server, migration, mysql-workbench

When we migrate from SQL Server to mysql only table structure and data  transfer, stored procedures, views and triggers don't transfer. Is there any why to transfer stored procedures and triggers using mysql migration help or any other tool? I'll be very thankful to help me. Why stored procedures and views do not transfer while I select both check boxes in ysql Workbench?:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that transferring database objects that contain code is not really straightforward and myqsl workbench does not transfer them automatically. See mysql workbench documentation on [Migrating from supported databases](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-migration-overview-supported.html):

> Generally speaking, only table information and its data are automatically converted to MySQL. Code objects such as views, stored procedures, and triggers, are not. But supported RDBMS products will be retrieved and displayed in the wizard. You can then manually convert them, or save them for converting at a later time.

I agree, this should be made more clear in the user interface of mysql workbench. There are other migration tools that claim to be able to automatically migrate such objects between ms sql and mysql (recommending tools is out of scope, but with some google serach you will find them), but I have yet to see an application that can truly migrate complex code from one rdbms to another.